# NSString, problem to create

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

I have a problem with creation to NSString.
The error is: "error: expected ']' before numeric constant".
The code is below.
Can you help me to find a solution for create these?

```
NSString *titleXML = [NSString  stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>"];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to escape the quotes in your string.  Try it like this

```
NSString *titleXML = [NSString  stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"];
```

Comment: First with the correct answer, but no example. I don't know if you win or not. Ha.

Comment: The example was only 30 seconds late ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You have quote characters embedded in your string, you need to escape them with backslash like this:

```
NSString *titleXML = [NSString  stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape your double quotes in the string using `\"`:

```
NSString *titleXML = [NSString  stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to escape those double quotes in the string for it to work. Like so:

```
NSString *titleXML = [NSString  stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"];
```